# Plain footer with remark

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

I am doing `LaTeX` now for a few years and so far for headers/footers I always used the `fancyhdr` package. Now I have updated my `TeX` version and wanted to create a new template for my work.

While using `fancyhdr` throws some errors I read that I should switch to `scrlayer-scrpage`. But I cannot find a simple example or good short documentation for my demands.

I simply want a plain page style with a remark on the right footer on every page after the abstract.

Is there any fast implementation for this kind of style?
Optimally in the same kind like fancy did?

**Solutions (tl;dr):**

1. Workaroud: Use the class-Option `enabledeprecatedfontcommands` to use `fancyhdr` again. I would not recommend that because `fancyhdr` seems to be outdated and have several problems with KOMA.
2. Use the implementation described in the accepted answer to switch to `scrlayer-scrpage`.

EDIT: Here are my errors:

```
! Class scrreprt Error: undefined old font command `\sl'.

See the scrreprt class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.117   \cleardoublepage


! Class scrreprt Error: undefined old font command `\sl'.

See the scrreprt class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.117   \cleardoublepage


Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (0.0pt): 
 Make it at least 14.49998pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.


! Class scrreprt Error: undefined old font command `\rm'.

See the scrreprt class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
[going on]
```

example code:

```
    \documentclass[%
        pdftex,
        oneside,        % Einseitiger Druck.
        12pt,           % Schriftgroesse
        parskip=half,   % Halbe Zeile Abstand zwischen Absätzen.
        headsepline,    % Linie nach Kopfzeile.
        footsepline,    % Linie vor Fusszeile.
        abstracton,     % Abstract Überschriften
        english,        % Translator
    ]{scrreprt}

%Kopf und Fußzeile
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%[...]

\begin{document}
        % Deckblatt
    \begin{spacing}{1}
        \input{deckblatt}
    \end{spacing}
    \newpage

    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\Roman{page}}
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    % Erklärung
    \input{erklaerung}
    \newpage

    % Abstract
    \input{abstract}
    \newpage

    \pagestyle{fancy}

    % whole content
\end{document}
```

A more detailed implementation of my template (older version) is online at [Github](https://github.com/MariusHerget/Ultimate-DHBW-LaTEX)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Always the same remark?

Comment: yeah always the same one

Comment: `fancyhdr throws errors` ... which errors? What have you done so far? I find `fancyhdr` very convenient in most applications

Comment: @ChristianHupfer similar errors to http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,85627.html To sum up the most forums/articles which discuss this error recommend to switch to scrpage when working with KOMA.

Comment: @Herget: Please post your code here, I am not going to GoLaTeX. But your post does not reveal that you are using KOMA at all, only in a comment. Who should guess this? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer updated my question :) hope you have all the necessary information now. I am currently building a template on another template from my university (see Github link).

Comment: @Herget: Well, `fancyhdr` **and** KOMA is really no good idea. I think the KOMA mafia will appear soon and answer this. (Templates are most times bad, as a side note ;-))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43829/discussion-between-herget-and-christian-hupfer).

Comment: @Herget: You used somewhere the deprecated (for mre than 20 years!= `\sl` and `\rm` instead of `\slshape` and `\upshape`.

Comment: Not me :) 'fancyhdr' seems to use them. If i comment out 'pagestyle(fancy)' everything works nice.

Comment: @Herget: Yes, that's true and it's hardcoded effective code, not patchable :-(

Comment: You can use the class-Option `enabledeprecatedfontcommands` to reenable to font commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, this works! But it seems to be more a hacky workaround than a real solution. And hacky workarounds often turn against you in the long run. Does somebody has a simple/good explained example for a  `scrlayer-scrpage` solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example how to change scrheadings:

```
\documentclass[%
        pdftex,
        oneside,        % Einseitiger Druck.
        12pt,           % Schriftgroesse
        parskip=half,   % Halbe Zeile Abstand zwischen Absätzen.
        headsepline,    % Linie nach Kopfzeile.
        footsepline,    % Linie vor Fusszeile.
        abstracton,     % Abstract Überschriften
        english,        % Translator
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\rofoot*{a remark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{blub}
\newpage
blblbl

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just implemented it and this works really good! Thanks.
My only problem ist, that it does not show any separation lines on the first page of every chapter. Do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: @Herget `painheadsepline`

Comment: The correct implementation i searched is `plainfootsepline` but thank you very much for the hint! This got me on the correct idea.